# Atualizar dados de turma com Array em Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, laravel

Tenho que atualizar vários registros na base mysql via ajax no laravel.

Existe uma lista de muitos professore com muitas matérias, porem eles fazem parte de uma turma em especifico.

Se alguém puder me ajudar muito obrigado.

**View:**

```
<select id="materia_id[]" name="materia_id[]" class="form-control"   required="true" >
   <option value="{{$materia->id}}"> {{$materia->nm_materia}} </option>@foreach($materias as $mat )<option value="{{$mat->id}}">{{$mat->nm_materia}}</option>@endforeach</select>
```

```
<select id="professor_id[]" name="professor_id[]" class="form-control"   required="true" >
   <option value="{{$professor->id}}"> {{$professor->nm_professor}} </option>@foreach($professores as $prof )<option value="{{$prof->id}}">{{$prof->nm_professor}}</option>@endforeach</select>
```

**Ajax:**

```
<script>
 var id = $("#id").val();

  $("#fEdit").on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     
    console.log(id)
    var dados = $('#fEdit').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type:'PUT',
   
        url:'/turma/atualizahorario/'+id,
        data:dados,
       success:function(response){
         
         console.log(response);
         //location.reload();
       },
       error:function(error){
         console.log(error);
       }
    });


  })
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
  public function update(Request $request,$id){ 
        //so atualiza todos os registro com o valor do ultimo registro
        for ($i=0; $i<count($request->materia_id); $i++) {

            DB::table('horarioturmaprofessor')
                ->where('horarioturma_id',$id)
                ->update([
                    'diasemana_id'=>$request->diasemana_id[$i],
                    'horario_id'=>$request->horario_id[$i],
                    'materia_id'=>$request->materia_id[$i],
                    'professor_id'=>$request->professor_id[$i],
                    
                ]);
    
        } 
}
```

Comment: Mas qual é sua duvida? Você simplesmente disse o que precisa fazer, não disse qual sua duvida quanto a isto.

Comment: Ola bom dia, desculpe. A minha duvida é como editar todos os professores, matérias, horários e dia da semana de uma só vez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A forma como você definiu os campos do tipo *select* permitirá apenas que um valor seja selecionado. Caso você queira que sejam selecionadas várias opções, terá que definir no campo *select* o atributo *multiple*, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
<select name="" id="" multiple>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

A documentação desse tipo de pode ser verificada nesse [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select).

Devido a essa condição, o laço *for* dentro da *controller* irá iterar uma única vez.

**Obs.:** estou considerando que a submissão do *form* via AJAX e a *controller* do back-end estejam funcionando corretamente.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, porem o ele ainda pega o primeiro campo.

Comment: Olha, dei uma boa olhada na sua pergunta e no seu código. A sugestão que dou é que você reformule a pergunta. Não deu para entender de fato o que você está precisando. A rota utilizada pela requisição via AJAX é utilizada para a atualização de um registro em específico (referente ao parâmetro ID). A controller utiliza esse mesmo ID para atualizar registros diferentes. Por isso está confuso.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, Mas a ideia era pegar o id da turma, onde contem vários horários, dia da semana, professores e disciplina e atualizar esses registros.